# Tensorflow 2.X : Understanding hinge loss

Tags: tf.keras, loss-function, tensorflow2.x

I am learning `Tensorflow 2.X`. I am following [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Hinge) to understand hinge loss.

I went through the [standalone usage](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Hinge#standalone_usage) code.

Code is below -

```
 y_true = [[0., 1.], [0., 0.]]
 y_pred = [[0.6, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6]]
 h = tf.keras.losses.Hinge()
 h(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
```

the output is `1.3`

I tried to manually calculate it & writing code by given formula

`loss = maximum(1 - y_true * y_pred, 0)`

my code -

```
y_true = tf.Variable([[0., 1.], [0., 0.]])
y_pred = tf.Variable([[0.6, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6]])
def hinge_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.maximum(1. - y_true * y_pred, 0.))

print("Hinge Loss :: ", hinge_loss(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
```

But I am getting `0.9`.

**Where am i doing wrong ? Am i missing any concept here ?**

Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `0` values of the `y_true` to `-1`. In the link you shared it is mentioned that that if your `y_true` is originally `{0,1}` that you have to change it to `{-1,1}` for the Hinge Loss calculation. Then you will get the same value for the example which is `1.3`.

> From the link shared: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Hinge
>
> y_true values are expected to be -1 or 1. If binary (0 or 1) labels are provided we will convert them to -1 or 1.

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = tf.Variable([[0., 1.], [0., 0.]])
y_pred = tf.Variable([[0.6, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6]])

def hinge_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.maximum(1. - y_true * y_pred, 0.))

# convert y_true from {0,1} to {-1,1} before passing them to hinge_loss
y_true = y_true * 2 - 1

print(hinge_loss(y_true, y_pred))
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(1.3, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```